# MacVIM Syntax file for CS

Tags: c#, vim

I am using MacVim to convert cs files to HTML. The convert function works fine. However, I don't like the default syntax highlighting for cs.

I understand that the cs syntax file in at /Applications/Vim/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/cs.vim, Maintainer by Anduin Withers. Not sure if there is any other way to substitute this one with a better syntax highlight file or update it with a a newer version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for colorscheme files. Syntax files define which part of text (source code) is what, for example it identifies keywords, function names and variables and so on. Color scheme defines what color should each component get.

To change color try

```
:colo <name of colorscheme>
```

To cycle through existing schemes use tab:

```
:colo <TAB>
```

You can [get new colorschemes](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/) (choose the ones you like and save as plain ascii files) and store them in your $HOME/.vim/colors directory which is searched by `vim` before the standard one that you mentioned above.

Comment: You can also do :color <ctrl-d> to list all installed color schemes

Comment: sort of. The color schema lists only limited options. On the one hand, I cannot find out one similar as VS default syntax color. On the other hand, I am looking for improved cs.vim to provide similar color markings as VS.

Comment: OK. I found your "get new colorschemes" has a lots of great color schemas. Thanks!